# How to make notification to user in Linux?

Tags: linux-mint, notifications, user

I wandering to know how to make notification to user in Linux Mint 17?

I want to do pause after every 50 min of PC work => and after this time make some notification, like:

> Please, make some break for 10 min

***How to achieve this?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution - `crontab`:

- install `sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin`
- check now `notify-send  "Notification Message"`
- write to `crontab -e`:

  > 50 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/notify-send -i /home/nazar/Pictures/icons/download_manager.png "Break" "Make a break for 10 min"

It should show notification exactly `<anyHour>:50`

where `download_manager.png` is:

[image]

And now we have next notification in Linux Mint:

[image]

Also, be aware that for Cinnamon some additional steps are required [Notify-send doesn't work at Cinnamon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247860/notify-send-doesnt-work-at-cinnamon/247865#247865)

Comment: I think notify-send has been installed by default in all the Mint iso's I've tried in the last few years, so *should* be in a default full install too. Could add a sound with 'play' too (vlc too but play is more command line friendly ;-)